# awk - problem while printing matching line

Tags: java, awk

I am trying to pass the matching line of a awk search command to some other program. I am doing something like

`tail -f file | awk 'tolower($0) ~ /debug|.*nfo/ {system("java -jar abc.jar $0")}'`

But am unable to pass the matching line to the external program.

Comment: What do you mean with that you are unable to pass the line ? Do you get an error ? If so, which one ? Also, did your try this: `... abc.jar \"$0\""` ?

Comment: I am doing `code` 
tail -f app.log | awk 'tolower($0) ~ /debug|.*nfo/ {system("echo $0")}' 
`code` But unable to get the matching line printed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO `"java -jar abc.jar $0"` is a problem here; you have to concat this string:

```
tail -f file | awk 'tolower($0) ~ /debug|.*nfo/ {system("java -jar abc.jar " $0)}'
```

Comment: Hi, When i try to pass the matching line as environmental variable, then its not working  

tail -f file.log | awk 'tolower($0) ~ /debug|.*nfo/ {system("java -jar -Dmsg= \"$0\" Test.jar ")}'

Comment: So do this: `tail -f file.log | awk 'tolower($0) ~ /debug|.*nfo/ {system("java -jar -Dmsg=\"" $0 "\" Test.jar ")}'`